# Composer me indica que los requisitos no han podido ser resueltos en un conjunto de paquetes instalables

Tags: laravel, composer

He intentado resolver este problema pero no logro que se solcuione, crei que el sistema que uso (Ubuntu 22.4) era el causante así que lo reinicie y sigue arrojando el mismo error, a alguien se le ha presentado este error?

Agradeciere mucho su ayuda o alguna referencia de como solucionarlo.

```
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/pint ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/pint[v1.0.0, v1.1.0, v1.1.1].
    - laravel/pint[v1.0.0, ..., v1.1.1] require ext-xml * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's xml extension.
  Problem 2
    - phpunit/phpunit[9.5.10, ..., 9.5.x-dev] require ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
    - Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ^9.5.10 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[9.5.10, ..., 9.5.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-xml --ignore-platform-req=ext-dom` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
```

Comment: muchas gracias, se soluciono ese error, me arrojo otros mas pero realice el mismo procedimiento y por fin funciona sin problemas. Muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solución:
Verifique la instalación de php-xml en ubuntu 22.04LTS

```
dpkg –list | grep php-xml
```

Para instalar php-xml en Ubuntu, actualice los paquetes de su sistema

```
sudo apt-get update -y
```

Después de actualizar los paquetes del sistema ahora instalamos el php-xml usando el siguiente comando.

```
sudo apt-get install -y php8.2-xml
```

Ahora verificamos nuevamente la instalación usando el siguiente comando.

```
dpkg –list | grep php-xml
```